# How can I get HE-AAC v2 to playback in Chrome's MediaSource API?

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio, aac, media-source

I am trying to use the [MediaSource API](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/) to play chunked HE-AAC v2 in Chrome.

Chrome explicitly allows this codec (`mp4a.40.29`) and as far as I can see [is capable](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/media/base/mime_util.cc&q=mp4a.40.29&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=326) of decoding it. (For example, the `decodeAudioData` method from the Web Audio API does decode the same data).

Unfortunately, trying to play chunks of HE-AAC v2 using the MediaSource API in Chrome results in the errors below, even though the exact same page works perfectly in Safari.

[I've put together a test page](http://chrome-he-aac-v2-test.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/test.html) demonstrating the problem (in Chrome) and success (in Safari).

How can I make Chrome play these chunks?

**Errors:**

> pipeline: decode error
>
> kInitDemuxer
>
> Append: stream parsing failed. Data size=15634 append_window_start=0
>   append_window_end=inf

Comment: If you were able to get somebody to try your test page in IE/Edge and let you know if it plays as expected there or not, that would be another useful data point to have. On the face of it, this looks like it's probably just a bug in Chrome (and I wish I had a suggestion for a workaround but I don’t).

Answer (score 0):

Your audio codec is HE-AAC which I believe is listed as a NOT supported audio codec on the Chrome Codec, Containers and File Extensions Support page http://www.chromium.org/audio-video

> AAC (Main only, not AAC-LC, AAC-SSR, HE-AAC) [Google Chrome only]